# Logback, Spring Boot - Remapping a log level for external libraries

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

Sometimes I've got third party libraries logging entries at incorrect levels. I'd like to be able to correct this.

I know I can do something along the lines of this

```
   <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
        <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator">
            <expression>return logger.equals("reactor.core.publisher.Operators") &amp;&amp;
                throwable instanceof software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.TransactionCanceledException;</expression>
        </evaluator>
        <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
        <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
    </filter>
```

In order to eliminate the log. But I want to be able to remap them. eg. change ERRORs into WARNINGs for specific classes.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.12.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/LevelRemappingAppender.html was also something that used to exist but it doesn't seem to be around in the 2.x release of Spring Boot.

Comment: I know I'm digging up the ancient past at this point, but hoping you may have found a solution to this... I've got two apps using the same internally-maintained library. One Spring Boot 2.6.9, the other is on 3.2.2. The library's log output is fine in SB 2.6.9, but the `info()` log are coming out in DEBUG in SB 3.2.2. This is the first thing I've found that's even close to being a match to this issue...